# How do I use collection as a parameter in SQL Server (2008) SP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So, I have this stored procedure (let's call it `SP1`) that gets as parameters two strings (say string1 and string2)

However, I need to call this stored procedure a lot from my code, so in order to make things faster, I was thinking of doing it in bulk. Collecting all of the parameters into a collection of some sort, and then send this.

From what I understand I need to use a `DataTable` on the code side, and a custom table type as the parameter on the SQL Server side - ok, cool. But...now what?

But... how do I get from there to the point where I actually go

```
EXEC SP1 string1, string2 or something along those lines?
```

Comment: So when you say, "however, I need to call this SP ALOT from my code", does the SP return any rows to do something with?

Comment: Nope. no return value. just an update.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table type

```
CREATE TYPE Strings AS TABLE ( String1 VARCHAR(50), String2 VARCHAR(50) )
```

Alter your procedure to accept table type as input

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Usp_procname (@strings STRINGS Readonly)
AS
..
```

To call the procedure

```
DECLARE @strings STRINGS

INSERT INTO @strings
            (String1,String2)
SELECT 'String1','String2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'String3','String4'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'String5','String6'

EXEC Usp_procname @strings
```

By this way you can pass more than one string in a single call. Make sure you update the logic inside the procedure to handle more than one string

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is what you like to achieve, instead of parsing those two string parameters, you would like to get a table holding all of the string row?
If so, you could you use `UDF` within SP,

Check here:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Name]
     (
     @parameter
     )
RETURNS @Table TABLE 
    (
    col1 varchar(50),
    col2 varchar(50)
    )
AS
BEGIN
**the query that inserts each records to TABLE**
END
```

Then using this `[Name]` UDF in your SP

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this one, I usually concatenate strings and split them on the server side or pass even an xml if I have multiple columns. Sql it's very fast when processing xml. You can try all the methods and check the processing time and after that choose the best method.